# LAN8720A transmits without TXEN signal being asserted

Tags: ethernet

I am trying to transmit some data with a LAN8720A [(datasheet)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/8720a.pdf) ethernet chip and I've encountered some strange issues. I've broken up the chip on the prototype board and connect it to the Spartan 6 FPGA. From the FPGA I pass the data to the two data pins TXD0 and TXD1, a TXEN signal and a 50 MHz clock to the XTAL1/CLKIN pin on the chip. I also provide a reset signal from the FPGA with the length of 200us. The data and TXEN signal are synchronous with the clock and toggle on the falling edge (I only output to the TXD0 for simplicity). The clock is provided continuously. The simulated picture of the waveform:

[image]

My configuration is as follows:
Mode pins - 011 : 100Base-TX Full duplex, auto-negotiation disabled. CRS is active during Receive.
nINTSEL - HIGH. The 50 MHz clock as I said is provided to the XTAL1/CLKIN pin.

The issue is that the chip outputs data on the TXP/TXN pins continuously, without  any regard for TXEN, even though the data should be transmitted only when TXEN is high. Here's the snapshot of the signal on the pins (probe is set to 10X):

[image]

My initial thought was that it was some sort of auto-negotiation, but I have the feature disabled so I doubt it.

The pins are connected to the magnetics on the ethernet connector.

When I catch the actual moment when TXEN is asserted there is no difference in the signal.

When I set the config pins to use auto-negotiation there is a small delay after powering up until some sequence of bits is being transmitted (which I assume is auto-negotiation protocol). There is no such delay when the auto-negotiation is disabled, the stream starts immediately after power up/reset.

When I set the config pins to use 10Base-TX the bandwidth is reduced, so there are packets sent with a long time of silence in between, but again the data doesn't seem to be dependent on either what I pass to the data pins, or TXEN state.

When I loop back the transmitted signal to the RX pins, I don't get any output on the data pins.

I don't know what I'm missing here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have forced the link state to 100Mbps, you are seeing the PHY transmitting the scrambled IDLE symbol continuously. Due to scrambling there is no visible difference between sending scrambled IDLE or actual data packed. So expecting a flat line when there is no transmission is false assumption. Does this explain what you are seeing?

Comment: Quite possibly, I guess I'll have to know what the IDLE symbol is after being scrambled, decode the signal from the oscilloscope and compare them. The weird thing is that when I try to loop the transmitted signal back into the RX pins I don't get any data out of the chip.  Maybe I should connect it to another chip completely.